# How to create ECDSA keypair (256bit) for bitcoin curve (secp256k1) using spongy castle?

Tags: java, android, encryption, bouncycastle, ecdsa

Currently, I am creating keyPair using this method

```
private  KeyPair getKeyPair() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchProviderException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException {
    KeyPairGenerator keyGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("ECDsA", "SC");
    ECGenParameterSpec ecSpec = new ECGenParameterSpec("secp256k1");
    keyGen.initialize(ecSpec, new SecureRandom());
    return keyGen.generateKeyPair();
}
```

`KeyPairGenerator` has another method, in which I can specify keySize but I am not sure how I will pass the keySpecs?

```
 public void initialize(int keysize, SecureRandom random)
```

Comment: are you using any third party library with this code ?

Comment: Yes, spongycastle library.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code is already sufficient, and specifying "secp256k1" already sets the correct size. The `initialize(int, SecureRandom)` method is an *alternative* to `initialize(AlgorithmParameterSpec, SecureRandom)`; you call one or the other, not both. If you call the one specifying the keysize (say, 256), the BC provider will try to choose a default curve of the right size (for 256, it will be "prime256v1" a.k.a. "P-256" or "secp256r1").

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation for KeyPairGenerator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/KeyPairGenerator.html) says that the `initialize(int, SecureRandom)` does this:

> Initializes the key pair generator for a certain keysize with the given source of randomness (and a default parameter set).

KeyPairGenerator is an abstract class, and I assume that this "default parameter set" is determined by a specific subclass you are using.  You might try to figure out what class your KeyPairGenerator object really is, and then consult the documentation of that class to learn where you can set its default parameters.