# Can't get read DSA keys from .pem files

Tags: java, openssl, digital-signature

I use openssl to generate public and private `DSA` keys and run the following commands:

```
openssl dsaparam -out dsaparam.pem 1024
openssl gendsa -out dsaprivkey.pem dsaparam.pem
openssl req -new -x509 -key dsaprivkey.pem -out dsacert.pem
```

And use the following two methods to load these keys:

```
public static PrivateKey loadPrivateKey() throws Exception {
    String privateKeyPEM = FileUtils.readFileToString(new File("/Keys/dsaprivkey.pem"), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

    // strip of header, footer, newlines, whitespaces
    privateKeyPEM = privateKeyPEM
            .replace("-----BEGIN DSA PRIVATE KEY-----", "")
            .replace("-----END DSA PRIVATE KEY-----", "")
            .replaceAll("\\s", "");

    // decode to get the binary DER representation
    byte[] privateKeyDER = Base64.getDecoder().decode(privateKeyPEM);

    KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("DSA");
    PrivateKey privateKey = keyFactory.generatePrivate(new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(privateKeyDER));
    return privateKey;
}

public static PublicKey loadPublicKey() throws Exception {
    String publicKeyPEM = FileUtils.readFileToString(new File("/Keys/dsacert.pem"), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

    // strip of header, footer, newlines, whitespaces
    publicKeyPEM = publicKeyPEM
            .replace("-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----", "")
            .replace("-----END CERTIFICATE-----", "")
            .replaceAll("\\s", "");

    // decode to get the binary DER representation
    byte[] publicKeyDER = Base64.getDecoder().decode(publicKeyPEM);

    KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("DSA");
    PublicKey publicKey = keyFactory.generatePublic(new X509EncodedKeySpec(publicKeyDER));
    return publicKey;
}
```

However, I can't get read neither public nor private key.

When I try to read public key, I get:

```
java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException: Inappropriate key specification: IOException: ObjectIdentifier() -- data isn't an object ID (tag = -96)
```

And when I try to read private key, I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException: Inappropriate key specification: IOException : algid parse error, not a sequence
```

If someone faced the same situation, I will really appreciate any help with regards to this problem

Comment: You should cat one of your public or private keys. I suspect its the difference between a "public key" and "subject public key info", where the latter has the algorithm and OID. Also see [How to read .pem file to get private and public key](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11787571/608639), [Load RSA public key from file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11410770/608639), [PublicKey from PEM file on android, java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45464949/608639), etc. Just swap RSA for DSA.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You aren't generating private and public key, you're generating private key and (X.509) *certificate*. A certificate *contains* a public key but *is not the same as* a public key.

To read an X.509 certificate in Java, use `CertificateFactory` (usually directly from a file) [(see javadoc online)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/cert/CertificateFactory.html) not `KeyFactory` (on a key-dependent `*Spec` class). Unlike `KeyFactory`(s), `CertificateFactory` can handle either PEM or DER input, so you don't need to do the strip-BEGIN/END and de-base64 yourself (unless you want to).

For the private key you have a problem similar to but not the same as the one jww commented about. For a public key file (which you don't have) OpenSSL does use by default the SubjectPublicKeyInfo format that Java calls `X509EncodedKeySpec` and OpenSSL internally calls `PUBKEY`. However for a *private* key file OpenSSL uses both its own 'legacy' formats *and* the standardized PKCS8 format, but Java's `PKCS8EncodedKeySpec` supports only the second of these, your commands are using the first, and converting between them in code is not trivial. You have three or maybe four choices:

- use openssl to convert to PKCS8-unencrypted:

   `openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -nocrypt -in dsaprivkey.pem -out dsaprivfixed.pem
   # or in 1.0.0 up
   openssl pkey -in dsaprivkey.pem -out dsaprivfixed.pem`

  Now you can read this with the posted code except the lines to remove are `-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----` and `-----END PRIVATE KEY-----` *without* `DSA`. As a small improvement, if you use `getMimeDecoder` you don't need to strip the whitespace yourself.
- generate PKCS8 (unencrypted) to start with, in openssl 1.0.0 up:

   `# you can generate the key within req instead of separately:
   openssl dsaparam -out params size
   openssl req -new -newkey dsa:params -x509 -nodes -keyout private.pem \
     -out cert.pem 
   # -nodes really means "don't encrypt key" for hysterical raisins 
   # or in config file set encrypt_rsa_key=no (yes even for other algos!)
   # or omit it and set encrypt_key=no (more sensible)
   #
   # or you can use (new) genpkey instead of (old) gendsa:
   openssl dsaparam -out params size
   openssl genpkey -paramfile params -out private.pem 
   openssl req -new -x509 -key private.pem -out cert.pem`

  Now you're in the same situation as above.
- use the PEM functionality in [BouncyCastle](https://www.bouncycastle.org) to read the legacy format. 

  See [Reading elliptic curve private key from file with BouncyCastle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22963581/reading-elliptic-curve-private-key-from-file-with-bouncycastle)
  and [How to Load RSA Private Key From File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3243018/how-to-load-rsa-private-key-from-file)
- read the legacy format (as you're doing now) and rebuild the PKCS8 ASN.1 encoding for it and then use `KeyFactory` on the PKCS8. This is a good deal more complicated and I don't recommend it. I do have a worked example for RSA (which is simpler) somewhere but I'm having trouble finding it; will add later if possible.